# Can any one provide detailed steps to add the material design in lower versions of android?

Tags: android, material-design

I have already developed an App.It has swipable tabs.Can I redesign the app to the material design.If yes please provide the detailed steps on it.:)

Comment: did my answer solved ur problem? if yes u should mark it as solved so that others with same issue can get help from this

Comment: @HirakChhatbar Or so you can get rep. Just be honest.

Comment: of course for rep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1** Create a new folder "values-21"

**Step 2** In that folder create a new xml "styles.xml".

**Step 3** in that xml, use all thems and attributes as Material Design.

Similarly do the same thing for layouts (create layout-v21) and u can use material design attributes like elevation and all.

Android phone will automatically inflate its views from the layout folders. If the phone is compatible with material design (i.e if it is running android 5), it will use layout-v21 folder, else it will use layout folder and same thing applies to values folder